# Get Next Array Element with Timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, wordpress

I tried to go over a WordPress (custom fields) array. I want to first print `array[0]`, after 6s print array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ot94.png) and so on until it gets to the end of the Array, then it should print `array[0]` again.

It once worked, but now it doesn't any more. I can't find the bug. It seems like in one interval of 6s it prints 2 quotes but always jumps over one. Eg. in the console it prints `1` and `2` & `3` and `4` at once, but in the `h2` it only sets `1` and `3`.

I also give you a screenshot of the quotes. This is the live example: http://www.inaregen.at/

```html
<!-- header.php -->
<h2 id="quote"></h2>
<?php
  $allQuotes = get_post_meta(19, 'zitat', false);
?>
<script>
  var quoteJson = <?php echo json_encode($allQuotes); ?>;
</script>
```

```js
// Quotes.js in footer.php
var prevQuote = null;
var getNextQuote = function() {
  if (prevQuote == null) {
    prevQuote = 0;
  }
  if (prevQuote == 0 || prevQuote > 0) {
    prevQuote += 1;
  }
  if (prevQuote == quoteJson.length + 1) {
    prevQuote = 0;
  }
  console.log(prevQuote);
  return quoteJson[prevQuote];
}

var setQuote = function() {
  var quote = getNextQuote();
  $("#quote").text(quote);
  setTimeout(setQuote, 6000);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  setQuote();
});
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ot94.png)

Answer (score 1):

I see you are having some issues handling all the `if...else` cases in the `getNextQuote` function.
You can make the code much more simpler by removing that function completely:

**NOTE:** this assumes that `quoteJson` isn't empty.

```
var quoteIndex = 0;

var setQuote = function() {
  var quote = quoteJson[quoteIndex];
  $("#quote").text(quote);
  quoteIndex = (quoteIndex + 1) % quoteJson.length; // calculate next index
  setTimeout(setQuote, 6000);
}
```

Comment: Using modulus (`%`) like this is a great way to handle most cases where you want to iterate an array and start at 0 again when you reach the end.

Comment: Oh yes, did not know this way :)
BUT it still jumps over the next array index. It shows index 0 then index 2 then 4  .... why? :/

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the index be the same as the array length.

Length starts at 1 but index starts at zero. So if the index equals the length...you have gone past end of array

Change:

```
if (prevQuote == quoteJson.length + 1) {
```

To

```
if (prevQuote == quoteJson.length) {
```

Comment: Yes ok thank you :) But that was not my problem :)
I was wondering why two array indexes are printed at once in the console, whilst one of them is missed out in the output.

Comment: Create a runnable version by switching out your php for simple javascript array and add some elements. See [mcve]

Comment: Open the page source and copy some of the relevant output

Comment: Just occured to me. Is the code shown inside a php loop and is being duplcated multiple times in page?

Comment: It is not inside a loop. I get the array this way:   <h2 id="quote"></h2>
                        <?php 
                        $allQuotes = get_post_meta(19, 'zitat', false); 
                        ?>
                        <script> 
                            var quoteJson = <?php echo json_encode($allQuotes); ?>;

                        </script>

Answer (score 0):

I just realised, that I need to out else if instead of if.
But now when it prints eg array[1] and it goes to the next interval, for 0.5s it shows array[1] and then it goes into the getNextQuote function.
Don't know how to solve this.
This is the array: (when i do console.log(array))

```
(10) ["Wie schee is des Gfüh, wann ma’s Fliagn probiert?", "Wie tiaf kånn ma foin, wann ma in Bodn verliert?", "Wie bleibt ma kloa und wie wird ma groß?", "Wann hoit ma fest? Wann låsst ma los?", "Kann I irgendwånn wieda so sei wie a Kind?", "Warum? Woher? Wohin? I fråg amoi in Wind", "Was bleibt nu offm, am Ende vom Kras?", "Was deaf ma hoffm, wenn ma goa nix mehr waß?", "Wie foit ma hin und måcht si nix draus?", "Wie fångt ma ån? Wie steht ma auf?"]
```

Comment: But it just never gets null & sets prevQuote to 0 .... it always takes 1... i don't get it...^^